# Restrict who can email enable a document library

Tags: document-library, email

I would like to restrict who can email enable a document library. The solution could be applied to a particular document library only or to the whole spweb or spsite is okay as long as we can accomplish this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely you are going to have to create a solution that will hide the link from the library settings page. If you can base this on permissions, that might be the best option for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lori. If I can restrict it to a particular SharePoint group is one way of doing it. Hiding the link through security-trimming is another way of doing it. Anobody who has experience of this or some directions through some blogs would be helpful.

Comment: I'd agree with Lori - you could use a 'HideCustomAction' element to hide the existing link to Email enabling, and then add a new CustomAction with a different rights requirement. Note that users who new the URL to the enable page would still be able to get there - but if I remember correctly, I think you need ManageLists permission on that list, which most users shouldn't have.